# Add new items to some structured array in a dictionary-like way

Tags: python, numpy

I want to extend the structured array object in numpy such that I can easily add new elements.

For example, for a simple structured array

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x=np.ndarray((2,),dtype={'names':['A','B'],'formats':['f8','f8']})
>>> x['A']=[1,2]
>>> x['B']=[3,4]
```

I would like to easily add a new element `x['C']=[5,6]`, but then an error appears associated to the undefined name `'C'`.

Just adding a new method to `np.ndarray` works:

```
import numpy as np
class sndarray(np.ndarray):
    def column_stack(self,i,x):
        formats=['f8']*len(self.dtype.names)
        new=sndarray(shape=self.shape,dtype={'names':list(self.dtype.names)+[i],'formats':formats+['f8']})
        for key in self.dtype.names:
            new[key]=self[key]

        new[i]=x

        return new
```

Then,

```
>>> x=sndarray((2,),dtype={'names':['A','B'],'formats':['f8','f8']})
>>> x['A']=[1,2]
>>> x['B']=[3,4]
>>> x=x.column_stack('C',[4,4])
>>> x
sndarray([(1.0, 3.0, 4.0), (2.0, 4.0, 4.0)], 
  dtype=[('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8')])
```

Is there any way that the new element could be added in a dictionary-like way?, e.g

```
>>> x['C']=[4,4]
>>> x
sndarray([(1.0, 3.0, 4.0), (2.0, 4.0, 4.0)], 
  dtype=[('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8')])
```

Update:

By using `__setitem__` I am still one step away from the ideal solution because I don't know how:

> change the object referenced at self

```
import numpy as np

class sdarray(np.ndarray):
    def __setitem__(self, i,x):
    if i in self.dtype.names:
        super(sdarray, self).__setitem__(i,x)
    else:
        formats=['f8']*len(self.dtype.names)
        new=sdarray(shape=self.shape,dtype={'names':list(self.dtype.names)+[i],'formats':formats+['f8']})
        for key in self.dtype.names:
           new[key]=self[key]

        new[i]=x

        self.with_new_column=new
```

Then

```
>>> x=sndarray((2,),dtype={'names':['A','B'],'formats':['f8','f8']})
>>> x['A']=[1,2]
>>> x['B']=[3,4]
>>> x['C']=[4,4]
>>> x=x.with_new_column #extra uggly step!
>>> x
sndarray([(1.0, 3.0, 4.0), (2.0, 4.0, 4.0)], 
  dtype=[('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8')])
```

**Update 2**
After the right implementation in the selected answer, I figure out that the problem is already solved by `pandas` `DataFrame` object:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x=np.ndarray((2,),dtype={'names':['A','B'],'formats':['f8','f8']})
>>> x=pd.DataFrame(x)
>>> x['A']=[1,2]
>>> x['B']=[3,4]
>>> x['C']=[4,4]
>>> x
   A  B  C
0  1  3  4
1  2  4  4
>>>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [`__setitem__()`](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/special_class_methods.html#fileinfo.specialmethods.setitem.example) magic method.

Comment: I try [this](https://gist.github.com/rescolo/c0c7dda3ea4d59f58958), `x['C']=[4,4]` was accepted but `x` itself was not updated

Comment: `self = new` doesn't change the object referenced at `self`, it just changes the name `self` to point to `new`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `numpy.recarray`instead, in my `numpy 1.6.1` you get an extra method `field` that does not exist when you subclass from `numpy.ndarray`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201817/adding-a-field-to-a-structured-numpy-array) or [this one (if using numpy 1.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288736/adding-a-field-to-a-structured-numpy-array-2) also discuss adding a field to a `structured array`. From there you will see that using:

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf
rf.append_fields( ... )
```

can greatly simplify your life. At the first glance I thought this function would append to the original array, but it creates a new instance instead. The `class`shown below is using your solution for `__setitem__()`, which is working very well.

The issue you found that led you to the ugly solution was [reported in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149269/subclassing-numpy-ndarray-problem). The problem is that when you do `self=...`  you are just storing the `new`object in a variable, but the entity `sdarray` is not being updated. Maybe it is possible to directly destroy and reconstruct the `class` from inside its method, but based on [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149269/subclassing-numpy-ndarray-problem) discussion the following `class` can be created, in which `ndarray` is not subclassed, but stored and called internally. Some other methods were added to make it work and look like you are working directly with `ndarray`. I did not test it in detail.

For automatic resizing a [good solution has been presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405342/automatically-resizing-numpy-recarray). You can also incorporate in your code.

```
import numpy as np

class sdarray(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.recarray =  np.recarray( *args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        if hasattr( self.recarray, attr ):
            return getattr( self.recarray, attr )
        else:
            return getattr( self, attr )

    def __len__(self):
        return self.recarray.__len__()

    def __add__(self,other):
        return self.recarray.__add__(other)

    def __sub__(self,other):
        return self.recarray.__sub__(other)

    def __mul__(self,other):
        return self.recarray.__mul__(other)

    def __rmul__(self,other):
        return self.recarray.__rmul__(other)

    def __getitem__(self,i):
        return self.recarray.__getitem__(i)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.recarray.__str__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.recarray.__repr__()

    def __setitem__(self, i, x):
        keys = []
        formats = []
        if i in self.dtype.names:
            self.recarray.__setitem__(i,x)
        else:
            for name, t in self.dtype.fields.iteritems():
                keys.append(name)
                formats.append(t[0])
            keys.append( i )
            formats.append( formats[-1] )
            new = np.recarray( shape = self.shape,
                              dtype = {'names'  : keys,
                                       'formats': formats} )
            for k in keys[:-1]:
                new[k] = self[k]
            new[i] = x
            self.recarray = new
```